# Using Linq to Order by Descending from a Method Return value

Tags: c#, linq

I have a class `AccountCommList` it has a property `Media` which could be Phone, Email, Paper, etc.

I need to make a call to another List which has whether the Media type `Phone` is a mobile or Landline (denoted by a 0 or 1), this other list also has an `importance` property showing order they perceive should be higher in the list denoting contact order. Here is the code I have.

```
    protected int RetrievePhoneType(string info, string acctNumber)
    {
        int type = xPhoneTypeList.Where(p => p.PhoneNum == info && p.AccountNum == acctNumber).Select(p => p.PhoneType).FirstOrDefault();

        return type;
    }
```

This code selects whether it is a cell or landline, keep in mind this PhoneTypeList also contains the `importance` property I need.

Here is the linq statement.

```
PhoneTypeListInfo xPhoneTypeList = new PhoneTypeListInfo();
AccountCommList commList = new AccountCommList(acct.AccountNumber, "WEBUSER");
AccountCommList cellPhoneList = commList.Where(x=> x.Media == "Phone").Where(x => 1 == RetrievePhoneType(x.Info, acct.AccountNumber)).OrderByDescending(?????).ToList();
```

I'm pretty sure I need to modify the RetrievePhoneType Method, but I'm not sure how to use a linq statement on a different list within the `commList`

**Edit**
Showing AccountCommList for posterity.

```
public class AccountCommList
    {
        public AccountCommList();

        public string ContactID { get; set; }
        public string Info { get; set; }
        public string Media { get; set; }
    }
```

**EDIT 2**

Showing PhoneTypeListInfo that has the Importance Property.

```
public class PhoneTypeListInfo
{

    public string AccountNum { get; set; }
    public int PhoneType { get; set; }
    public string PhoneNum { get; set; }

    public int Importance { get; set; }

}
```

Comment: Can you show the code for `AccountCommList`?

Comment: @roryap Updated, added to Edit.

Comment: You still haven't mentioned on what property you want to order the list?

Comment: OrderBy takes a key selector, so you do something like: OrderBy(x => x.ImportanceValue).

Comment: @glenebob the `ImportanceValue`is in the `PhoneTypeList` which is not the AccountCommList

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the return type to PhoneTypeListInfo.

```
protected PhoneTypeListInfo RetrievePhoneType(string info, string acctNumber)
{
    var type = xPhoneTypeList
        .Where(p => p.PhoneNum == info && p.AccountNum == acctNumber)
        .FirstOrDefault();
    return type;
}
```

Then use the LINQ comprehension syntax. Thus it is easy to associate collections.

```
var cellPhoneList = (from x in commList
                     where x.Media == "Phone"
                     let p = RetrievePhoneType(x.Info, acct.AccountNumber)
                     where 1 == p.PhoneType
                     orderby p.Importance descending
                     select x).ToList();
```

Anyway, your method always returns the first found object. So sorting is impossible.

Comment: Maybe I'm not understanding this, but I'm getting more than one result, I pass in my second `Where` clause, `x.Info` which there are multiple x.Info's, RetrievePhoneType returns the first one in the `AccountCommList` that matches each x.Info?

Comment: @ChrisClark - Ok. Glad you have everything working. Perhaps I misunderstood the structure of your classes. Happy coding!

Comment: Follow Up question, and I'm sure you knew this was coming, is there a way to keep `p` alive? I can't seem to access the `PhoneType` afterwards?

Comment: Try `select new { x, p }` instead of `select x` ?

Answer (score 0):

try

```
.OrderByDescending(p=>p.YourProperty)
```

Comment: This won't work because the `YourProperty` is on a separate list.

Comment: ok, what if you generate cellPhoneList  without ordering it AccountCommList cellPhoneList = commList.Where(x=> x.Media == "Phone").Where(x => 1 == RetrievePhoneType(x.Info, acct.AccountNumber)).ToList();

Then you do something like commList.Select(x=>new{ you generate the object as desired}).OrderByDescending(p=>p.property);

Comment: that way you can join the other object